# Why does it matter to Mocha's `before()` whether the function passed takes parameters or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js, chai

I have code like this in my `describe`: `before(a)`.

When `a` looks like this:

```
function a() {
  return chai.request(app)
    ...
    .then(res => {
      res.blah.should.blah;
      return Promise.resolve();
    });
}
```

...everything works great (it's a very quick call.)

However, when I make `a` take some input variables:

```
function a(dummy, my_var) {
  return chai.request(app)
    ... // use my_var here
    .then(res => {
      res.blah.should.blah;
      console.log("finished!");
      return Promise.resolve();
    });
}
```

The promise never resolves.  Two observations:

1. `finished!` *does* get properly output (immediately)
2. `dummy` is populated.

It's populated with this:

```
function (err) {
    if (err instanceof Error || toString.call(err) === '[object Error]') {
        return done(err);
    }
    if (err) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(err) === '[object Object]') {
            return done(new Error('done() invoked with non-Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err)));
        }
        return done(new Error('done() invoked with non-Error: ' + err));
    }
    if (result && utils.isPromise(result)) {
        return done(new Error('Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.'));
    }
    done();
}
```

I don't know where that's from exactly, but I don't need it, that's why I just put it into a dummy variable.

Now I suspect that has something to do with it, but I wonder why my workaround doesn't do the trick here.

I still want to use `before(a)` for the default case, leaving `my_var` undefined.  When I do actually want to pass that variable, I intended to:

```
before(() => {
    return a('my_content');
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Mocha inspects the function you pass to `before` to check how many parameters are [defined on it](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/fb1e0830b5e235326b58b25da9f07c42da363404/lib/runnable.js#L52) like this:

```
 this.async = fn && fn.length;
```

If there's any parameter defined, then the function is deemed to be asynchronous. (Mocha also checks if it returns a promise but that's a different test.) If there's at least one parameter defined, then Mocha passes as 1st parameters a function that you are meant to call when your `before` callback is done doing its work. That callback (traditionally named `done`) is useful for code that does not use promises.
If you do not call it, then Mocha waits forever even if you return a promise.

Note that Mocha does the same with all other hooks: `beforeEach`, `after`, etc., and with the callback you pass to `it`.

Comment: Enlightening explanation.  That's too bad...no backward-compatible way to do my change then.  Oh well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mocha `before`, `after`, `it` function accepts one parameter - callback. It should be defined and called when your test uses async functions:

`db.connect` is async function:

```
before(done => {
  db.connect(done);
}
```

When `db.connect` returns a promise you shouldn't use callback and could return the promise:

```
before(() => {
  return db.connect();
}
```

In your code, you call `before` with `a` function, which accepts two parameters. Mocha interprets the first parameter as callback, and tries to call it.

To prevent this issue, you need to call `a` function directly and pass params in it:

```
before(() => {
  return a(dummy, my_var);
}
```